# SQLSTATE[HY000] Error in Laravel: failing to add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have tried almost all the answers here, my migrations are in order, I have set the engine to 'InnoDB', I have set the `user_types_id` to unsigned. I think I am missing out on something, I am not able to migrate this. ( I was able to manually add the FK from phpMyAdmin though).
My `user-types` are created before my users table is created, I did ensure that :)
Migrations:

```
Schema::create('user-types',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and the users table:

```
  // I think I saw this somewhere, too 
  Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

  Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('user_types_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('users',function(Blueprint $table){
        // When I index it I am able to manually add fk from
        // phpMyAdmin
        $table->index('user_types_id');
        $table->foreign('user_types_id')->references('id')->on('user_types');
    });
```

Comment: This issue was a a simple typographical error (See revision history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is name differences in your schema defination.

You are creating table with `Schema::create('user-types',function(....` where table name is `user-types` but when you are setting up foreign key you are passing `user_types`

So make them same whichever is correct. Either `user-types` or `user_types` and then it will work.

Comment: I wasted almost 6 hours with this. :/

Comment: if that is true then it should be closed as off topic because typos can not be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

You can give reference like this also

```
Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->foreign('user_types_id')->references('id')->on('user-types')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->integer('user_types_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints(); //Remove this its not require,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write,

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); // disable foreign key checks while creating tables which are dependant on each other
```

at the top of your schema definition where you are facing this problem, it should work.